# Python/Tkinter: root as a class / initializing instance variables in a tkinter class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a custom tkinter root window with customized title bar and other modifications, as a class. The class is saved in a module named ModRoot. The relevent code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Rt(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self,winhght,winwdth,apptitle):
    super().__init__()

    # initialize instance variables
    self.winhght = winhght
    self.winwdth = winwdth
    self.apptitle = apptitle
```

In the main application, this root window is created with two lines of code, and the addition of the mainloop.

```
import ModRoot
RootWindow = ModRoot.Rt(400,800,"App Title")
RootWindow.mainloop()
```

I have two questions:

First, this root window works fine but, as I have learned in the past, there are sometimes problems with a particular approach that are not immediately evident. So the first question is simply whether or not the above approach to creating a root window is acceptable and correct.

The second question has to do with initializing the instance variables (self.winhght = winhght and so on). Strangely enough, I have found that if I comment these lines out, the class works just as it did before. Yet, every tutorial on classes indicates that these variables must be initialized. If that's the case, why is this class working with those lines commented out? And are they actually necessary?

Comment: I see that your code initialises `self.winhght`, but not that it is used later. Why do you need these attributes?

Comment: Because later in the module code is the line:

self.geometry(f"{winwdth}x{winhght}")

I did not include the entire module code in the question.

Comment: So you use the parameter `winhght`, but not the attribute `self.winhght`. So delete the assignments. I love it when programmers can just delete code.

Comment: Yes it's fine. However I would probably just update the Tk (`self`) width, height and title in `__init__` rather than save them as variables. Also if you have more I would suggest using underscore prefixing to avoid conflicting with `Tk` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the first question is simply whether or not the above approach to creating a root window is acceptable and correct.

Yes, it's acceptable.

> Yet, every tutorial on classes indicates that these variables must be initialized. If that's the case, why is this class working with those lines commented out? And are they actually necessary?

It's impossible for us to say. Do you use `self.winwdth`, `self.winhght`, and `self.apptitle` anywhere else in the code? You only need to initialize them if you need them later.

Comment: Well, for example I pass in 'winhght' and 'winwdth' when creating an instance of this class, then later in the module code I have the line: self.geometry(f"{winwdth}x{winhght}"). So yes, those two variables are used later in the module. But the module seems perfectly happy even when they are commented out.

Comment: @fmex: it doesn't matter if you use `winwidth` and `winhght`. The question is, do you use `self.winwidth` and `self.winhght`? If you don't use them anywhere, then you don't need to define them.

Comment: In my approach to tkinter, all of my widgets are defined as classes, each stored in a separate file. Those files are imported as modules into the main application. And then, in each case, an instance of the widget class is created in the main application. The root window above is a good example. Since the import statements simply import a module containing a class definition, and the classes are only then instantiated inside the main application itself, I am guessing that I can do away with the  "if __name__ == "__main__" statements in the main application and modules. Correct?

Comment: To clarify further, my tkinter widget modules might define a method (for example, a frame might have "Show" and "Hide" functions). But these would never be actually called inside the module iteslf. They would only be called from the main application. That is why I am assuming that I don't need the "if name == main" code lines.